# Cannot Center Left StartDrawableIcon Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, user-interface

I'm currently new in android developer especially using XML as UI, now I'm studying about TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText but I'm facing a problem where my startdrawable icon cannot be centered, and I dont know why

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_logo_binar"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_monetization_on_24"
        app:startIconGravity="center"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tie_cost_of_service"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```